# Overwriting an existing object in an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the object `DataEntry` with row, column, and value variables and I am trying to add a new object to an ArrayList unless there is already an object with the same row and column values then I overwrite the `value` with a new value right now i have this:

```
public void set(int row, int column, double val) {
        DataEntry temp = new DataEntry(row, column, val);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            if (data.get(i).getRow() == row && data.get(i).getColumn() == column)
                data.set(i, temp);
            else {
                data.add(temp);
            }
}
```

It is not setting the value properly, i think it has something to do with `data.get(i).getRow()`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: *i think it has something to do with data.get(i).getRow()* - maybe you are right, but why do you think that?

Comment: I think you will be better of if you use a `Map<Point, Double>` (where `Point` has the variables `row` and `column`). That way you can use `.contains` and `.put` instead of looping the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i think at data.get(i) it just returns the value at i instead of the Row

Comment: @Stefan im not sure what Map<Point, Double> is?

Comment: Why dont you use HasSet<DataEntry>, and overide hashcode() and equals() method in your DataEntry class. it will take care of everything .(If you are not maintaining insertion order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you keep searching no matter whether the `i`th item in `data` matches the rows and columns or not.

What you should do instead, is to return from the method when you find a matching `i`, otherwise continue. If the loop finishes without finding a matching index, add `temp` to `data`:

```
public void set(int row, int column, double val) {

    DataEntry temp = new DataEntry(row, column, val);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        if (data.get(i).getRow() == row && data.get(i).getColumn() == column) {
            data.set(i, temp);
            return;
        }
    }
    data.add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in your code snippet. The else block should be executed after the loop as followed.

```
public void set(int row, int column, double val) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    DataEntry temp = new DataEntry(row, column, val);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        DataEntry current = data.get(i);
        if (current.getRow() == row && current.getColumn() == column){
            data.set(i, temp);
            isFound = true;
            break;
      }
    }

    if(!isFound) {
        data.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method in your DataEntry class and then use the [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method of list to check the existence of entry object.